# Firebase Options returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I recently moved my gcm project to firebase as suggested by google. Ever since then I have been having troubles and the current documentation does not provide enough answers. This is my problem

```
 FirebaseOptions.from resource(this)
```

Returns null. The documentation says this could be as a result of missing applicationId from the string resource.

Comment: How about using `getOptions()` of `FirebaseApp` ?

Comment: Also, Have you put `google-services.json` in your app module ?